# AWS-CDK Running ECS container on a Fargate schedule: Schedule not observed

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

Our team does a ton of scheduled automation work that we would like to move to the cloud. Much of it is already dockerized, which makes moving it to ECS trivial.

What I Want

What I want to do is create a Docker image, push it to ECR, and have that image run as a container every 15 minutes and exit when complete. All the container needs to do is run the script to completion (takes only a minute or so) and shut down.

What Is Happening

The synth and deploy work. The repository and image are created, as are the cluster, service, task, and schedule. Unfortunately, however, my container is spun up every minute instead of every fifteen in the schedule I have created. [edit] I can see in the logs that the container ran successfully.

What I Suspect

I suspect that despite everything I have tried, AWS doesn't know the health state of the container when it exits, so it retries it. I am operating under the assumption that the task should end when the container exits, but maybe I am wrong or missing something.

What I Have Tried

So far I have tried setting retries to 0 in my stack definition, and forcing my script to exit with sys.exit(0) when complete, but nothing seems to work. I have tried both cron and duration and neither setting has changed the outcome.

Other Options

I am betting the advice is going to be adding a container-backed lambda and running that instead of the container directly. I'd like to avoid the additional complexity if possible, but if I have to go that route, I can.

I'd appreciate any comments or suggestions to get around this issue!

Regards,
Bruber

Comment: Is the container actually starting up and running? Or is it failing because it can't pull a docker image or something? As long as an ECS Scheduled task actually starts successfully, ECS will not re-run the task again until the next scheduled time. I think something is actually failing in the ECS task startup process. You definitely do **not** need Lambda for this. What you are trying to do is exactly what ECS Scheduled Tasks does out of the box. Less second-guessing what we are going to tell you, and more details (actual code/logs) in the question would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info in the original message. I can see in the logs that the container runs and successfully outputs the container's Python version.

Comment: Add you CDK code to the question. It is not clear how you're configuring the schedule - the proper way is to use scheduled tasks, but that wouldn't involve a service (those are for long-running jobs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're describing, a [single-node job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-definition-Fargate.html) in AWS Batch sounds like a better fit. As long as your job exits with 0, it'll trigger success for the job.

AWS Batch leverages ECS to run your containers and simplifies the orchestration.